# Why is my jpeg not appearing in my webpage?

Tags: html, css

All I want to do is embed an image from my computer into this webpage.  The image file is Avery.jpg, and it is on C:.  Could my path be wrong, or am I doing something else completely wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color:#CCFFFF;
                <!--Baby Blue???-->
            }
            p {
                color:#800080;
                font:100px Verdana, sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
        <title>birthday.html</title>
    </head>

    <Body>
        <img src="Avery.jpg" alt="avery" />
        <p>Happy Birthday!</p>
    </Body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying in your local machine or server? what is the error in developer tools like firebug?

Comment: your path is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: Your image is in the working dir?

Comment: 1. If you won't upload your image as well, it will work only on your computer. 2. Is this page in the same directory of the image?

Comment: Paste  your jpeg image in root folder of your webpage.

Comment: You're path is most likely what's wrong. Try loading the image from the same directory your index.html file is located.

Comment: your image doesn't exist if it doesn't appear. Is it on a server? Or is is a stand alone html file? If it is in C:/ try this `src="file:///C:/Avery.jpg"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will appear normally if you put the image in the same root folder of your web page.

Answer (score 0):

Put the HTML file and the image file in same location and try. It will work for you.